# tycho clean launching configuartion

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, tycho

I want to use tycho in order to test my eclipse plugins. My test class just lists all the installed bundles for the first time. 
I have experimented with building and installing bundles. Now I need to start the framework without my experimental bundles, but I do not manage this. The list still comprises all the bundles I have ever installed.

My eclipse-test-plugin module uses tycho-surefire-plugin which is configured with `<appArgLine>-clean</appArgLine>`.

I have hoped to launch the OSGi framework without any cached data, old not used bundles etc. I have also tried with `<argLine>-Dosgi.clean=true</argLine>` but did not succeed. I look for something like "Clean the configuartion area before launching" in eclipse settings.

I have got a feeling I miss something elementary and essential.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call Tycho with something that involves the `clean` lifecycle of Maven, e.g. `mvn clean verify`, the tests will be executed in a fresh Equinox runtime.

So if you are still seeing your "experimental bundles" in the test runtime, this is because your test has a dependency to them. The test runtime by default contains exactly your test bundle and all its transitive dependencies.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! I really had some unnecessary dependencies.